# R: Combine elements and remove indice in vector

Tags: r

Say we have a vector like

```
x <- c("I", "sleep", "every", "day", "all", "night")
```

How would you manipulate this vector above so that we get something like
"I-sleep" "all-night" by combining the two elements together and removing out the `x[3]` and `x[4]` indices at the same time? Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What went wrong? Edit the question to include this information or it will likely be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you ask

```
x <- c("I", "sleep", "every", "day", "all", "night")
i <- 1
while (i < length(x)){
  if(i %in% 3:4){
    i <- i+1
    next
  } else {
  print(paste(x[i], x[i+1],sep="-"))
  i <- i+2
  }
}
```

Output :

```
[1] "I-sleep"
[1] "all-night"
```

Comment: Thank a lot. This problem was giving me a headache... And I am not sure why I got down-voted because it's not really a simple question when I am new to R...

Comment: No problem, if you are satisfied with the answer, please click the check mark at the top of  the answer so this question can be considered closed.

Comment: PS it got downvoted because you didnt post what solutions you have tried. Contributors like to see that OPs have made an effort to come up with a solution that they can help improve

Answer (score 0):

ok.. your question is pretty simple. You will find answer to such questions by just googleing. but here is quick fix

```
x <- c("I", "sleep", "every", "day", "all", "night")
c(paste(x[c(1,2)],collapse="-"),paste(x[c(5,6)],collapse="-"))
# [1] "I-sleep"   "all-night"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version when there are more elements in the `vector`.  After removing the 3rd, and 4th elements, convert it to a `matrix`, then to `data.frame`, and use `paste` within in `do.call` to join the elements by row

```
do.call(paste, c(as.data.frame(matrix(x[-(3:4)], 
                      ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)), sep="-"))
#[1] "I-sleep"   "all-night"
```

---

Or use a two step process by subsetting with a logical `vector` through recycling and then `paste` it one step

```
x1 <- x[-(3:4)]
paste(x1[c(TRUE, FALSE)], x1[c(FALSE, TRUE)], sep="-")
#[1] "I-sleep"   "all-night"
```